# Parsing data from XML file with multiple of same name attributes in PHP

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I am trying to parse data from the XML below (I shortened the data a lot to give an example of what the data looks like).

For each attribute, I would need to store the data in a separate array.

XML File

```
<report>
    <title>Resolution Times (Jun 07 00:21)</title>
    <sets>
        <set>
            <legend>Solved in Less than 2 Hours</legend>
            <values>
                <value data="8702" date="2012-05-24"/>
                <value data="8741" date="2012-05-25"/>
                <value data="8741" date="2012-05-26"/>
                <value data="8741" date="2012-05-27"/>
            </values>
        </set>
        <set>
            <legend>Solved in Less than 24 Hours</legend>
            <values>
                <value data="36990" date="2012-05-24"/>
                <value data="37094" date="2012-05-25"/>
                <value data="37096" date="2012-05-26"/>
                <value data="37144" date="2012-05-27"/>
            </values>
        </set>
    </sets>
</report>
```

Below is some test code I am doing to try and read in the data. For testing purposes I am just printing out to see what data is actually pulled.

```
$verifyReport = new SimpleXMLElement('305262.xml', null, true);
$testing = $verifyReport->sets->set->values->value;

echo '<ol>';
foreach($testing as $data)
{
    echo '<li>',
    $data['data'].PHP_EOL;
    echo '</li>';
}

echo '</ol>';

$testing1 = $verifyReport->sets->sets->values->value;

echo '<ol>';
foreach($testing1 as $data2)
{
    echo '<li>',
    $data2['data'].PHP_EOL;
    echo '</li>';
}

echo '</ol>';
```

Below is out the output of the data

```
1. 8702
2. 8741
3. 8741
4. 8741

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in 
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/tango/test.php on line 23
```

I am able to pull in the first set (Solved in Less than 2 hours) ok, but when I try to pull the data from the second set (Solved in Less than 24 Hours), I get the above error.

Can anyone help correct this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second block you have `$testing1 = $verifyReport->sets->sets->values->value;` So I guess the second `sets` has to be `set` instead. But anyway, why don't you iterate over `$verifyReport->sets` and read the further values inside of your for loop?

```
new SimpleXMLElement('305262.xml', null, true);
foreach ($verifyReport->sets->set as $set) {
    echo '<ol>';
    foreach ($set->values->value as $data) {
        echo '<li>',
        $data['data'] . PHP_EOL;
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ol>';
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! Now, I'm just trying to figure out how to store each set of data in separate arrays.